# Simplify function for removing duplicate array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, duplicates

I want to find div element that contain custom attribute **mod** than append that div to list item. But first I have to remove **divs** that contain duplicate mod value. Here's what I have done

```
<div class="list"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div mod="dog"></div>
    <div mod="man"></div>
    <div mod="woman"></div>
    <div mod="dog"></div>
    <div mod="bird"></div>
    <div mod="insects"></div>
    <div mod="dog"></div>
</div>
```

this is my script

```
modArr($('.container').find('[mod]'))

function modArr(el){
        var filterArray = [] // store mod
        ,   modNames = [] // store mod value
        ,   arrIndex = [] // store non duplicate index
        ,   li = [] // store
        modArray = el

        // store mod value
        for(var i=0; i < modArray.length; i++){
            modNames.push($(modArray[i]).attr('mod')) // get mod value from div
        }

        // search for non duplicate mod value and get the index of none duplicate mod
        for(var i=0; i < modArray.length; i++){
            if(filterArray.indexOf(modNames[i]) === -1){
                filterArray.push(modNames[i])
                arrIndex.push(i) // push non duplicate index value
            }
        }

        filterArray = [] // reset filterArray

        // push module from modArray to filterArray using index in arrIndex
        for(var i=0; i < arrIndex.length; i++){
            filterArray.push(modArray[arrIndex[i]])
        }

        // push to li array
        $.each(filterArray,function(i,el){
            li[i] = '<li>'+ el.outerHTML +'</li>'
        })

        $('<ul></ul>')
            .append(li.join(''))
            .appendTo('.list')

    }
```

What you can see is that I've used to many loops, is there any simple way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: So, do you want to remove all the duplicated instances or want to keep one of them?

Comment: I want to keep want of them

Comment: http://pagedemos.com/qcjkz8mqaq2r/ is a very fast way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an object as a map for checking duplicates, see comments (I've added text to the mod divs so we can see them):

```js
modArr($('.container').find('[mod]'));

function modArr(elements) {
  // A place to remember the mods we've seen
  var knownMods = Object.create(null);
  // Create the list
  var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
  // Loop the divs
  elements.each(function() {
    // Get this mod value
    var mod = this.getAttribute("mod");
    // Already have one?
    if (!knownMods[mod]) {
      // No, add it
      knownMods[mod] = true;
      ul.append($("<li></li>").append(this.cloneNode(true)));
    }
  });
  // Put the list in the .list element
  ul.appendTo(".list");
}
```

```html
<div class="list"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div mod="dog">dog</div>
    <div mod="man">man</div>
    <div mod="woman">woman</div>
    <div mod="dog">dog</div>
    <div mod="bird">bird</div>
    <div mod="insects">insects</div>
    <div mod="dog">dog</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

We can also just use the DOM to check for duplicates, but it's a bit slower (not that it matters for the number of elements here):

```js
modArr($('.container').find('[mod]'));

function modArr(elements) {
  // Create the list
  var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
  // Loop the divs
  elements.each(function() {
    // Get this mod value
    var mod = this.getAttribute("mod");
    // Already have one?
    if (ul.find('div[mod="' + mod + '"]').length == 0) {
      // No, add it
      ul.append($("<li></li>").append(this.cloneNode(true)));
    }
  });
  // Put the list in the .list element
  ul.appendTo(".list");
}
```

```html
<div class="list"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div mod="dog">dog</div>
    <div mod="man">man</div>
    <div mod="woman">woman</div>
    <div mod="dog">dog</div>
    <div mod="bird">bird</div>
    <div mod="insects">insects</div>
    <div mod="dog">dog</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note: I used `this.cloneNode(true)` rather than `outerHTML` because there's no need to take a roundtrip through markup. If you want more jQuery there, it's `$(this).clone();` ;-) Similarly, if you don't like `this.getAttribute("mod")`, there's `$(this).attr("mod")`.

---

I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that `mod` is an invalid attribute name for `div` elements. You can use any name you want starting with `data-`, though, so perhaps use `<div data-mod="dog">` instead.

Comment: Nicely explained! I'll use `<div data-mod="dog">` instead. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, only adds if an element with `mod` is not already in `list`:

```js
$('.list').append('<ul>');
$('.container [mod]').each(function(index, el) {
  if($('.list [mod=' + $(el).attr('mod') + ']').length === 0) {
    $('.list ul').append($('<li>' + el.outerHTML + '</li>'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div mod="dog">Dog1</div>
    <div mod="man">Man1</div>
    <div mod="woman">Woman1</div>
    <div mod="dog">Dog2</div>
    <div mod="bird">Bird1</div>
    <div mod="insects">Insect1</div>
    <div mod="dog">Dog3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the answer I was looking for also. But I voted T.J Crowder answer because he explain it thoroughly. Thanks! :)